# Open new window from a status bar app with no dock icon

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have made a macOS app in Swift 4 that only displays a status bar icon and menu, and I have disabled the doc icon by setting the "Application is agent" to YES. My app has no storyboard and no window. How do I create/open a new window when choosing a menu item? I have tried creating a NSWindowController with a companion xib and calling showWindow(nil) on the NSWindowController instance, but nothing happens.

How can I dop this, and can I also make sure it gets displayed and becomes active as the active "app" on top of any other app's?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27999114/2303865

Comment: Thank you, my searches did not find it. Should I close/delete this question?

Comment: you are welcome. You can leave it as it is